# Implementing noise model in Quantum simulator

Tags: simulation, noise

I have noticed that a few papers, such as [this one](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/f917/bce4c341a6601dc4a4aa8a41452c6ee82054.pdf), provide models two for typical noise that a qubit encounters during network transmission:

1. Λ is **the dephasing channel**
   Λ(ρ) = Pq(ρ) = qρ + (1 − q)ZρZ
   *where ρ is a single qubit state, Z is the Pauli Z gate, and q ∈ [0, 1] is the noise parameter.*
2. Λ is **the depolarizing channel**
   Λ(ρ) = Dq(ρ) = qρ + (1 − q)1/2
   *where ρ is a single qubit state, 1/2 is a maximally mixed single-qubit state, and q ∈ [0, 1] is the noise parameter.*

I would like to implement this in the SimulaQron program, but I don't really understand how to calculate the effect on the qubit. What exactly do I have to do to the qubit to apply this noise?

Nor do I understand the value of q. My interpretation is that q would occasionally be 1, and occasionally be 0, to vary the effect on the qubit. However, if I change q probabilistically, doesn't that eliminate the point of modelling the noise?

Answer (score 2):

It is important to realize that the depolarizing and dephasing channel (and pretty much any other noise model for that matter) **do not represent unitary operations.** This means there is no unitary operation (that takes qubit states to qubit states) corresponding to these channels.

Rather, channels are more general: they map density operators to density operators. If you are not familiar with density operators (often denoted with $\rho$), I strongly advice you to first familiarize yourself with the concept. They are a framework that allows for the (more general than 'normal' or* *pure* states, denoted with the ket notation:$|\psi\rangle$) **statistical mixtures**: a statistical mixture of actual pure qubit states. The population of the various pure states determines the density matrix.

A typical noise channel creates statistical noise: therefore you need the density operator framework to describe these channels. As far as I am aware, the simulaqron software was not designed to account for density operators - it only works with pure states. This limits the possibility of simulating a quantum channel as a noise process significantly.

The only thing that would be possible tom simulate the dephasing channel is to gather statistics by repeating the same circuit over and over, but sometimes injecting a Z error (with probability $1-q$). (*see bottom note)

For the depolarizing channel, a different but equivalent definition of this channel is:

\begin{equation}
\Lambda_{depo}(\rho) = (1-p)\rho + \frac{p}{3} X\rho X+ \frac{p}{3} Y\rho Y+ \frac{p}{3} Z\rho Z,
\end{equation}
so you could apply a random $X$,$Y$ or $Z$ with equal probability of $\frac{p}{3}$, instead of only the $Z$ operation as with the dephasing channel.

- Note that it is customary to write the dephasing channel as $\Lambda_{deph}(\rho) = (1-p)\rho + p Z\rho Z$, so with the probabilities flipped compared to your definition.